# Convert pointer to pointer in C++ to Numpy Array in Cython

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy, cython

I am working on an algorithm that leverages Cython and C++ code to speed up a computation. Part of the computation involves keeping track of a 2D matrix, `vecs` that is D x D' dimensions (e.g. 1000 x 100). The algorithm parallelizes within Cython to set values per column. I am then interested in then obtaining the `vecs` values as a NumPy array in Python.

### Modifying vecs in Cython

The pseudocode for setting each column of `vecs` is something like:

```
# this occurs in a Cython/C++ function
for icolumn in range(D'):
   for irow in range(D):
      vecs[irow, icolumn] = val
```

### Data structure for vecs

To represent such a matrix, I am using a pointer of pointers of type `npy_float32` (which I think is just numpy's float 32 type). I have a pointer to pointer array now that looks like this:

```
ctypedef np.npy_float32 DTYPE_t    
cdef DTYPE_t** vecs             # (D, D') array of vectors
```

### Goal to obtain the vecs in NumPy Array at the Python Level

I am interested in converting this `vecs` variable into a numpy array. This is my attempt, but it doesn't work. I'm pretty novice at C++ and Cython.

```
numpy_vec_arr = np.asarray(<DTYPE_t[:,:]> proj_vecs_arr)
```

Comment: C++ libraries to do what exactly? Convert to numpy? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: what is your `vecs` in the cirst part of your Cython code ? If you use MemoryViews such as `cdef float[:] vecs = np.zeros()` you can later get it back with `return vecs.base`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in NumPy nor Cython, but I do know some about C++ and about interoperating C++ with other languages.

What problem are you trying to solve?

Answering that will prevent the XY problem, and might allow folks here to better help you.

Now, answering your original question.  I see two ways to do this.

1. Use an available constructor of the NumPy array to construct a NumPy array. This will clearly give you a NumPy array, problem solved.
2. Create an object with the same in-memory structure as the NumPy array that Python expects, then convert that object to a NumPy array. This is tricky to do, bug prone, and depends on many implementation details. For those reasons, I would not suggest taking this approach.

Comment: Hi @brbusby, thanks for your response. I have added additional details. I wasn't sure how much info is useless vs useful. Hopefully this is more informative about the problem I am trying to solve?

Comment: To interop with numpy arrays, you'll need an pointer to a flat data buffer, e.g. a C style array. Then from Cython, use a typed memory view, as you wrote in the OP.